# What is the purpose of OpenSSL::X509::ExtensionFactory

Tags: ruby

Why standard library of ruby suggests to create factory and only then add extensions to certificate ?

```
ef = OpenSSL::X509::ExtensionFactory.new
ef.subject_certificate = our_cert
ef.issuer_certificate = ca_cert
our_cert.add_extension(ef.create_extension("subjectAltName", "DNS:augustl.com, DNS:*.augustl.com", false))
```

Why we cant just do

```
our_cert.add_extension(OpenSSL::X509::Extension("subjectAltName", "DNS:augustl.com, DNS:*.augustl.com", false))
```

Why ExtensionFactory need issuer_certificate and subject_certificate? What I can do with ExtensionFactory?

Comment: I have figured it out: e.g. authorityKeyIdentifier is different when Factory is not used